# Can $LL^T$ decomposition of a matrix be computed by the same algorithm as $LU$-one?

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods

I know that's the silly question. But if I perform $LU$ decomposition on a symmetric positive definite matrix, will this decomposition be the same one as $LL^T$ one?

Answer (score 1):

No, not necessarily: given a symmetric matrix $A$, the $L$ of the $LL^{T}$ decomposition need not be the same as the $L$ in an $LU$ decomposition. (Of course, the $LL^{T}$ decomposition is a valid $LU$ decomposition).

Consider, for example, the case where $A$ is positive definite. 
Then, the $LL^{T}$ (Choleskly) decomposition is unique. 
On the contrary, the $LU$ decomposition is not unique: given an $LU$ factorization we can obtain an $L'U'$ factorization where $L'$ and $U'$ are lower and upper triangular, respectively, by appropriately rescaling the columns and rows of $L$ and $U$.